# Most approachable text / intro on Faynman-Kac Theorem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

I am looking for an advice / a recommendation on a PDF or a text-book that would be suitable for tackling the Feynman-Kac Theorem for the first time (think of a Graduate probability student with keen interest in Stochastic processes). Would anyone be able to recommend "an approachable" text?

Ps: even though I already got a great textbook recommended in the comments, I welcome as many tips as possible!

Comment: Kleinart is very detailed, probably more than what you want, but worth a browse ("Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics, Statistics, Polymer Physics, and Financial Markets")

Comment: @user619894: Wow! That book looks AMAZING!! I already love the "Preface to First edition" from the author !

Comment: yeah, only 1,500 pages to go ...

Comment: see Shreve "Stochastic Calculus for Finance II", ch. 6.4

Comment: Thank you, @c-walk!